# Hiding a parent element using JS/JQuery based on the alt tag of a child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My portfolio website has a Wordpress backend, and I use a Wordpress gallery to produce links to my various projects.  It is getting somewhat bulky now, however, and I would like to give visitors the ability to filter the number of options based on categories.  Such as "Design", "Graphic Design", etc.

Each element in the gallery uses the following code:

```
<dl class='gallery-item'>
    <dt class='gallery-icon landscape'>
        <a href="Page Link" target="_self" class="no-lightbox"><img width="250" height="250" src="Display Image" class="attachment-full" alt="Design" /></a>
    </dt>
    <dd class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>
        Description of Page
    </dd>
</dl>
```

I can control the text of the alt tag when the img is declared.  What I'm looking for is to design a link that calls a JavaScript function that would hide the parent  element if the child img element has a specific alt tag.

Is this something that can be done?  I've looked and been trying several things but so far I haven't even come close.

Comment: It's not recommended to use `alt` for "special" purposes, since it affects accessibility...

Comment: Complementing @tcooc comment: Add `data` attributes to your elements to store this kind of information. ie: `data-area="Design"`

Comment: Anyway... Short answer: `$('[alt="Design"]').parent().hide()` http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: I totally agree. Also, use a template engine if you do not want to duplicate the content between the `alt` and the `data-....` attributes.

Comment: Quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/kf5pr2n0/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can hide the parent, based on the child's attribute:

Js (vanilla) :

```
//Consider "el" as the <a> clicked element
if(el.children[0].getAttribute("alt") == "Something") {
    el.parentNode.style.display = "none";
}
```

Jquery:

```
//Consider "el" as the <a> clicked element
if($(el).find("img").is("[alt='Something']")) {
    $(el).parent().hide();
}
```

But as commented, you should set another property for that other than `alt`, for it has a different purpose...

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you could put this in a data attribute that would be better suited for such an application, but given the specific context you have here, something along the lines of:

```
$("#hideDesign").click(function() {
        $("[alt='Design']").parent().toggle();
})
```

Where "#hideDesign" is the ID of an element that you want the user to click on to toggle the view of that particular type of element.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't manipulate the `img` tags and give them a `data` attribute, you can still rely on the `alt` attribute to achieve that.

Just to illustrate, I'm considering the markup below:

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="">Please select...</option>
    <option value="Design">Design</option>
    <option value="Graphic Design">Graphic Design</option>
</select>
<br />
<dl class='gallery-item'> <dt class='gallery-icon landscape'>
        <a href="Page Link" target="_self" class="no-lightbox"><img width="250" height="250" src="Display Image" class="attachment-full" alt="Design" /></a>
    </dt>

    <dd class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>Description of Page</dd>
</dl>

<dl class='gallery-item'> <dt class='gallery-icon landscape'>
        <a href="Page Link" target="_self" class="no-lightbox"><img width="250" height="250" src="Display Image" class="attachment-full" alt="Graphic Design" /></a>
    </dt>

    <dd class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>Description of Page</dd>
</dl>
```

And using jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    // When the user selects a gallery item to display.
    $('#mySelect').on('change', function () {
        // We hide all of them.
        $('.gallery-item').hide();

        // If there's actually something selected.
        if ($(this).val()) {
            // Select the image which alt is the value selected, 
            // and show its parent which class is gallery-item.
            $('[alt="' + $(this).val() + '"]').parents('.gallery-item').show();
        }
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/kf5pr2n0/)

Just to complement, the other way round:

```
$(function () {
    // When the user selects a gallery item to hide.
    $('#mySelect').on('change', function () {
        // We show all of them.
        $('.gallery-item').show();

        // If there's actually something selected.
        if ($(this).val()) {
            // Select the image which alt is the value selected, 
            // and hide its parent which class is gallery-item.
            $('[alt="' + $(this).val() + '"]').parents('.gallery-item').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/kf5pr2n0/1/)